# GeoDjango & SpatiaLite - filtering nearby objects

Tags: python, django, django-orm, geodjango, spatialite

My `models.py` has User and Business models that have this field:

```
location = PointField(geography=True)
```

I'm getting Google Maps coordinates (in **EPSG 4326**) via Geocode service from an address which the user specifies.
Then I'm saving it in the above field (also **EPSG 4326**).

Now, what I want is to get all Business objects within a specified radius (of 1km for example), based on the user location:

```
Business.gis.filter(location__distance_lt=(request.user.location, D(km=1)))
```

But it doesn't work, it gives me this error:

> ValueError: SpatiaLite does not support distance queries on geometry
>   fields with a geodetic coordinate system. Distance objects; use a
>   numeric value of your distance in degrees instead.

So, does anyone know how to properly solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I resorted to converting it to projected system before doing query. It works that way, although it's not so precise but it my case that's not a concern.

Comment: Hey @MikiSoft, I posted a bit of a late answer, have a look.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Hey, I solved it long time ago in the way I described above, but I've marked your answer as solution nevertheless to thank you for the effort. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theory:**

This is a pretty obscure error related to those two:

- [GeoDjango dwithin errors when using django.contrib.gis.measure.D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194710/geodjango-dwithin-errors-when-using-django-contrib-gis-measure-d?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Geodjango distance query not retrieving correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165491/geodjango-distance-query-not-retrieving-correct-results)

Since you are using geodetic coordinate systems (like the **EPSG 4326**) you need to provide the distance in degrees.

Here is a very good explanation on how to transform km to degrees accurately enough: [How do I convert kilometres to degrees in Geodjango/GEOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217348/how-do-i-convert-kilometres-to-degrees-in-geodjango-geos?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Finally I would suggest to use the [`dwithin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-dwithin).

---

**Praxis:**

- `1km ~= 0.008 deg`
- The query now should look:

  ```
  Business.gis.filter(location__dwithin=(request.user.location, 0.008))
  ```